# Find Text in a Google Doc and Remove it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a script that auto fills a Doc template based on values in a sheet.

It works perfectly, however when the cell in the sheet is blank, and I remove the relevant text from the template.. i.e:

```
if (targetCell.isBlank()){
  textToRemove = "";
}
```

This works fine and removes the {{}} values. However, it leaves the line that the text was on. So since there are several {{}} values, in the doc it has went from this:

```
{{Value1}}
{{Value2}}
{{Value3}}
```

and if only Value3 is there, it ends up:

```
Value3
```

with the 2 blank lines above,
instead of:

```
Value3
```

I tried something like this:

```
var removeText = function (body, searchText){
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    const r = next.getElement();
    const rStart = next.getStartOffset();
    const rEnd = next.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    body.editAsText().deleteText(rStart, rEnd);
  };
```

but this is throwing getStartOffset is not a function..

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So I have a script to populate a template.

In the template there are fields such as:

{{Value1}}
{{Value2}}

I pull these values from certain cells. but when the cell for Value1 is empty, I want to remove {{Value1}} from the Doc. I have done this by using setText(""); 

This method works but it still leaves the line that the text was on there. So essentially, If Value1 Cell is empty, I want to remove it and remove the line/paragraph it was on so that {{Value2}} moves up to where {{Value1}} was.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But, now, I noticed that your question has already been resolved. I'm glas your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out after some digging.

```
function removeUnused(body, text) {

  var paras = body.getParagraphs();
  var i = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
    if (paras[i].getText() === text){
      paras[i].removeFromParent()
  }
 }
}
```

body is the body of the copy of my template Doc.

```
  var templateCopy = template.makeCopy("TEST1", destinationFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(templateCopy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
```

Set the text you want to search for and run the function:

```
var searchText = "Value1";
removeUnused(body, searchText);
```